# Easiest way to enable Google authentication for GWT application? (non-GAE-hosted)

Tags: java, gwt, google-authentication

What is the easiest way to enable existent GWT application authenticate users using Google account? I tried googling (lol) it but have found no solutions that could work out of the box. Is there a library to solve this problem in like 10 lines of code?

P.S. The application I've mentioned isn't hosted at Google Apps if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been looking at [gwt-oauth2](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/wiki/GettingStarted) for this purpose recently. It looks pretty decent, and the docs are straightforward. Perhaps it could be of interest.

Comment: I've seen your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7534374/852604. Gwt-oauth2 is not about **authentication**, it's about **authorization**, which seems to be not what I really need. Update: I mean't your *first* answer ;-)